# Nginx basic auth on specific location

Tags: nginx, authentication, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app and would like basic Nginx Basic Auth on specific location and now I am doing it like

```
location / {
        passenger_enabled on;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-FORWARDED_PROTO https;
        proxy_redirect off;
}

location /somelocation {
        auth_basic "Restricted";                                #For Basic Auth
        auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/etc/nginx/.htpasswd;    #For Basic Auth

        passenger_enabled on;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-FORWARDED_PROTO https;
        proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Rails can do it inside controllers, see [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) for details:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
   http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: :index

   def index
     render plain: "Everyone can see me!"
   end

   def edit
     render plain: "I'm only accessible if you know the password"
   end
end
```